# SWIFT: Navigation bar color is not displaying properly (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I have the following storyboard setup:

[image]

For some reason, the navigation bar style (i.e. the color) does not carry over to the RSVP view controller (it shows as a darker blue than what was selected in the nav controller). I've tried changing it programatically as suggested by other posts, however, it didn't seem to fix it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried adding the following into both ViewWillAppear and ViewDidLoad, but it was not effective (note: I'm just using the greenColor() as a test to see if the colour changes):

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: Put that line of code at the start of the app before the storyboard is loaded.

Comment: In addition to what rmaddy said, I think you want `barTintColor`, not `backgroundColor`.

Comment: Thanks guys... Would that be the AppDelegate? Sorry I'm fairly new to swift.

Comment: Nav bar transparency is also something that can alter the color to something you weren't expecting.